# What is the relation between the two notions: modular curves and semistable elliptic curve

Tags: field-theory

Let $C$ be an elliptic curve over rationals.

My **question** is: What is the relation between the two notions: modular curves and semistable elliptic curves.

Comment: Since $C$ is modular there is always a modular curve $X_0(N)$ that surjects onto $C$. Is this the type of thing you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find now that all semistable elliptic curves over the set of rational numbers are modular. This is the answer.